# xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost5000/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED / Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react-native

basically  i'm making a signup page with react for the front and node js / express for the back , and i'm using mysql for the database , i successfully connected to my db but my problem is when try to signup i get those 2 errors :
(1. POST http://localhost5000/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)
(2.ncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84))

it supposed that those data pass from front to back to db , but i get those errors ,i couldn't fix them

Comment: You need a `:` between `localhost` and `5000`

Comment: Unless your hostname really is `localhost5000` which seems unlikely since the error message says it can't convert that name to an IP address. (Voting to close the question because the problem is caused by a typo)